What type is the component marked TH
Picture shows more of the print with component marked TH.

The component is at input 29 V AC to the rectifier circuit.
What type and value could it be?

Welcome! Could you zoom out a bit?

I have added a picture more zoomed out.

What rectifier circuit do you refer to? Please post the circuit diagram that you have collated.

It's probably a Littelfuse 0468001.NRHF which is a disposable 1A fuse.

Here's a picture from LCSC to confirm. The 1206 size seems reasonable from the picture as well.


Excellent find!

Whoever invented the phrase "no user serviceable parts inside" was thinking about this fuse.

I am overwhelmed by the support I have received - Based on the last information I have ordered parts now :-D
